# Crooked steering became straight after tyre rotation

Tags: tires, power-steering, alignment, wheels

In october last year I bought 4 tires for my car and at same time got the alignment and balancing done. After that the steering wheel angle was a little bit crooked, as the car neither glided to any direction on its own and after observing the tyre wear being normal I let it stay that way. But now after I have done more than 6000km decided to rotate the tires as instructed in the manual. After rotation to my surprise the crooked steering became straight again. So is this normal or could it be a bent wheel rim ?

Comment: It doesn't seem normal, but a bent wheel/rim would not be the issues (or the cure, in this case). If the wheel was bent, it would wobble. You would feel a bobble in the steering wheel which would be a constant vibration. The steering wheel being off center should only be fixed by a change how the steering rack aligns with the wheels. Are you sure they didn't do an alignment check for you when the rotated your tires? Or did you do the rotation yourself?

Comment: did the rotation myself @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Comment: Bad tire.......